# JSON parse error on running `hugo` command

Tags: hugo

I'm trying to build a blog using Hugo. Every time I run the `hugo` command, I get this error

```
ERROR 2021/06/22 18:57:50 JSON parse error: expected comma character 
or an array or object ending on line 52 and column 40
   12:     {
           ^
Total in 145 ms
Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: JSON parse error: 
expected comma character or an array or object ending on line 52 and column 40
   12:     {
           ^
```

I suspect my project directory structure to be the problem but I'm open to more questions about the situation.

My project directory structure looks like

```
root-folder
  --content
    --posts
      --my-first-post.md
    --posts-again
      --my-second-post.md
  --my-third-post.md
  --my-fourth-post.md
```

and all markdown files contain exactly the following

```
---
title: "Project"
date: 2021-06-22T18:09:26+01:00
draft: false
---

This is a post
```

When `draft` is set to `true`, I don't get the error when I run the `hugo` command. The error comes up when `draft` for any of the files in `posts` or `posts-again` is set to `false`
I have searched every file for a line 52 that I can understand but I cannot find any.

Where could this error be coming from and how can I resolve it?

`hugo serve` and `hugo serve -D` work fine, but `hugo` doesn't

Comment: @PenelopeStevens I just followed the instructions at [Hugo quick start](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/) but used the [Hugo papermod theme](https://github.com/adityatelange/hugo-PaperMod) instead. I don't know about any JSON config file. I've also searched for the term `json` all over the project but I've come up with nothing. No file also ends in `.json` in the project

Answer (score 1):

Issue is baseurl set to "/" in config.toml.
Change it to "" and try

Answer (score 0):

hugo-PaperMod is missing a comma in a JSON block in layouts/partials/templates/schema_json.html

I got this error and just pushed up a PR to fix it
https://github.com/adityatelange/hugo-PaperMod/pull/614

this may be your issue